# Intent constructor arguments undefined

Tags: java, android

I want to start an activity, so I picked this Class way. I know I can do it easily by passing ACTION NAME directly in intent constructor but I am learning android so I trying to learn new ways. I started another activity with the same code in other class and it working there but here it is giving the following error. I think it has to some thing with THREAD class.

The error is:

```
The constructor Intent(new Thread(){}, Class) is undefined.
```

How can I solve this?
Here is the code:

```
package com.umer.practice2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    Thread timer= new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
        try
        {
            sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.umer.practice2.StartingPoint");
            Intent myintent= new Intent(this,ourclass); // error
            startActivity(myintent);
        }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

Here is the layout of the class activity which is giving force close error.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:id="@+id/fdisp" 
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="How many times you eat in a day"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/but3" 
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the code of the class itself

```
    package com.umer.practice2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyClass extends Activity{

    Button b3;
    TextView disp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but3);
         disp= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fdisp);

         b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    disp.setText("It depends ");
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the intent creation by:

```
Intent myintent= new Intent(SplashScreen.this, StartingPoint.class);
```

Otherwise, `this` refers to the enclosing `Thread` class

Comment: Ok there is another class and the code is completly correct. But when I try to open it from the menu, Android SDK pops an error of Force Close. Why is this so.

Comment: What if you replace `ourclass` by `StartingPoint.class` ?

Comment: And you probably should not `finish()` the activity in `onPause()`... (just don't override the `onPause() method, that may fix your problem)

Comment: I used finish for the splash screen inorder to end its lifecycle otherwise it will be there when i go back from an activity.

Comment: Why don't you `finish()` it when starting the intent (in the thread) ?

Comment: So what does the OnPause() function does ? The tutorial I am following, the guy says, We should call finish() in onpause() funciton.

Comment: `onPause()` is called when the activity goes to background (e.g when user presses HOME button). In your case you want to finish the splash activity after the sleep, i.e when starting the next activity.

Comment: Yes. And I want to end the splash screen when it does to background. I am gonna past the code and you check if some thing is wrong

Comment: But the thread will continue even if you finish your activity...you should do that with a handler (instead of a thread) so that you can cancel the waiting task if you explicitly finish your activity before the timeout

Answer (score 0):

you can call as given below

```
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.class, StartingPoint.class);
```

It will work. Try it.